# Jquery Display Hidden Section Not Working - JSfiddle Included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that is suppose to show a hidden `<div>` when you click on a checkbox. I can't seem to figure out why the section won't show. Below is the script I have...

Here is a **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/cWagP/)**  To see the checkbox scroll down to where it says "add spouse", the section is hidden there.

```
 $.appicant.applicants();
 $('#spouse').live('click', function () {
     alert('s');
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('.spouse-content').slideDown();
     } else {
         $('.spouse-content').slideUp();
     }
 });
```

Comment: live is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9 https://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** , because **[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**  method is deprecated in jQuery version 1.7+ and removed in 1.9+

```
$.appicant.applicants();
 $('#spouse').on('click', function () {
     alert('s');
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('.spouse-content').slideDown();
     } else {
         $('.spouse-content').slideUp();
     }
 });
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/5QqYL/)</kbd>

As ,@KevinJantzer said , there is some problem with line  `$.appicant.applicants();`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your demo with the fix:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWagP/5/)

You needed to change `live` to `on`. I also had to comment out this line:

```
$.appicant.applicants();
```

As it was causing JS to fail.

Answer (score 0):

`live()` is [**removed**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) as of jQuery version `1.9`. Since you've included jQuery `1.10.1` then you need to use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead:

```
$('#spouse').on('click', function () {
    alert('s');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.spouse-content').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.spouse-content').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Also you're not include the `applicants` plugin which results in this error as well:

```
Cannot call method 'applicants' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.applicant.applicants();
```

is throwing an error. Fix that and the rest of your code is working. Also, use "on" in place of deprecated "live".